# Powershell Bulk upload to S3

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to bulk upload all files within a directory to S3. Based on this forum (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=149164) it looks like keyprefix should do the trick. However I cannot seem to get my command to work:

```
Write-S3Object -BucketName bucket-here -KeyPrefix 'j:\drive\dir\
```

I have my creds saved through `Set-AWSCredential`

When I execute the command it says

```
Supply values for the following parameters:
Folder:
```

Which is confusing because I thought I specified the location I wanted it to upload with the KeyPrefix parameter.

Comment: Can you post the error you receive?

Comment: double check single quotation at the end of the line ? i think you miss one .
also i think windows like double quotations more than single quotations, try that too

Comment: Looks like when you specify `-KeyPrefix`, you put it into the parameter set for `UploadFolder` documented here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Write-S3Object.html - and -Folder is the source folder on your local machine, the KeyPrefix is the destination 'folder' in S3. Maybe `Write-S3Object -BucketName bucket-here -Folder 'J:\Drive\dir' -KeyPrefix 'JDriveDir'` will work?

Comment: @Javad in PowerShell, single quotations are for literal strings and double quotations are for 'expandable strings' that you can directly put variables in and they will be replaced with the value. For a string like `"j:\drive\dir"` either type of quotes will behave the same, it's only if they have dollar symbols or backtick escapes that they will be different.

Comment: Side-note: You could instead use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). It has `aws s3 cp --recursive` and `aws s3 sync` that can do it quite simply.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler So it seems that dosnt work either. It is now saying that the directory specified by the -Folder parameter does not exists. The location is a mounted network drive so I am not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Also @JohnRotenstein the location is on a windows network drive so that is why the powershell. I would definitely prefer to use the CLI if it wasn't a samba drive.

Comment: Also for reference I can see the files correctly using get-content so I assume my drive is mounted correctly.

Comment: You can use the AWS CLI with a network drive. Have you had any problems doing so?

Comment: I am using a windows server currently. Can I install AWS CLI within powershell?

Comment: Ok @JohnRotenstein I have installed the aws CLI but I still cannot get it to see my network drive path the command I am using is aws s3 sync s3:/bucket/location 'j:location\'

Comment: If you are copying from your local computer to S3, the syntax would be: `aws s3 sync j:\directory s3:/bucket/directory`

Answer (score 0):

Ended up writing a powershell script from the example here(http://volkanpaksoy.com/archive/2014/12/04/uploading-files-to-s3-using-windows-powershell/)

```
$results = Get-ChildItem .\path\to\files -Recurse -Include "*.pdf" 
foreach ($path in $results) {
    Write-Host $path
    $filename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($path)
    Write-S3Object -BucketName my-bucket -File $path -Key subfolder/$filename -CannedACLName Private -AccessKey accessKey -SecretKey secretKey
}
```